# OllyDbg : 'Label expected' issue

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

Well, as newbie in reverse engineering, i tried to use 'inline patch' technique to patch the program, then i got stuck on this point :

[image]

[image: 2]

Assemble window keep giving me message 'Label expected', so i edit that instruction to name label, such as 'myfunc'.

But when i tried to assemble codes like 'MOV ECX, 0C', it worked properly.

Why 'Label expected pop up and how to solve this issue?

(Program i'm trying to patch is ap0x's patchme_no1.exe)

Comment: Have you tried simply using `MOV ECX, 4012a8` or `MOV ECX, 0x4012a8` or `MOV ECX, 4012a8h`?

Comment: Read that error as `Label unexpected`.   Just enter `MOV EAX, 004012A8`

Comment: @MargaretBloom 

Thanks for your comment! It helped a lot :)
By the way,  I stumbled upon a new issue.. How can i assemble code like

> ASCII "Nag Patched", 0
> ASCII "Unpaced", 0

I tried to edit code memory with ascii numbers, I failed.
I tried to edit hex dump with ascii numbers, i also failed.

I really want to patch this nag.. but i cannot put ascii characters :(


![This is my trial.. It seems image is not seen in the comment!](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/26838115/45685649-f8db5100-bb84-11e8-9422-ee860567fab3.png)

Comment: feel free to ask reverse engineering questions on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question Number one  remove the unpackme. and enter pure address
the string "unpackme.40xxxx" is treated as label
ollydbg tries to locate the label and fails

if you want to use it as it is
you can label some address with that string using the **COLON : keyboard shortcut**

below are two screen shots one with the error 
other no error because the address has been labelled for reference

label expected error

[image]

the address is labelled now this label can be used in assemble dialog

[image]

for second question in comment

you cannot assemble an ascii string inplace
you need to use ctrl+e to edit

[image]